Downloading Google signed GSI
I need to use google signed GSI for my compatibility tests.
I am able to download unsigned GSI from below site.
https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-android13-gsi/grid?legacy=1
But, downloaded GSI is unsigned.
How to get Google signed GSI? Is there any method to sign my downloaded GSI with Google?
I have tried testing with unsigned GSI. But, Facing few issues due to this unsigned thing.
